# Design of heatsink - increase in ambient temperature during heat transfer

Tags: mosfet, switches, heatsink, bms

I have gone through few resources available online on how heat flow from die to ambient and how its is modelled as current source, thermal resistance and ambient temperature as voltage source.
I have to design a MOSFET circuit carrying high current and want to limit its junction temperature (T1) to less than 100°C and my ambient temperature (T2) should not be greater than 50°C. (System view is it's a battery pack where cells are series paralleled and the BMS and the MOSFET carrying the current, acting a BMS switch all are under the same enclosure.) To lower the T1 I need to lower the thermal resistance and heatsink is used for this purpose.

Heat flow = temperature difference / Rth (thermal resistance)

Temperature difference (T) = T1 - T2

If I design have parameters -**max. junction temperature at 90°C and max ambient temperature as 50°C (cells get derated above 50°C so I want the temperature inside the pack less than that).**

When heat is transferred from die to ambient, the ambient temperature will also raise and if T2 raises T is reduced and my heat T is directly proportional to heat flow which affects my heat flow increasing my junction temperature.

Is my understanding correct? If so then for the design requirements shared above what values (ambient temperature) should I consider while calculating for the heatsink?

Comment: Temperature is not modelled as a voltage source, the resulting voltage (not a source) represents temperature.

Comment: Generally, you assume Tambient is constant. This is probably a good assumption if you have constant air flow.  At the boundary of your heat sink, the air temperature will be higher.  How much depends on how much air flow (mass flow) you have, and how much heat you're trying to pull away.

Comment: If your "ambient" temperature is rising as a result of operating your circuit, then it isn't ambient. You have an additional thermal resistance between the heatsink and true ambient that you need to add to your thermal model.

Comment: @SteveSh theres no constant air flow, as mentioned in the post the ambient to the MoSFET is battery, BMS and the air inside the closed pack

Comment: @DaveTweed by saying ambient we assume that environment is free flowing air ? So in my case where the DUT(MOSFET) is inside the pack  (with a still air), I have to modelled the thermal resistance from heat sink to still air which is inside the the pack and resistance from still air to outside pack , Am I right ?

Comment: @Andyaka in application note slvaez0 from TI models Ambient temperature as dc voltage source to run a simulation in pspice.

Comment: @KIRAN - So then what happens outside the closed pack?  IMM, the ambient in this case is not the air in the battery pack, but rather the air surrounding the battery pack.  The thermal capacity of the air inside the battery pack and the thermal resistance of the pack walls to the real ambient all need to go into the thermal model.  If the pack is a perfect thermal insulator, then the temp of the air inside will increase without bounds.

Comment: Thanks @DaveTweed for the help, I will be trying to model thermal resistance of the still air inside the pack, Rths-air, Rth air - pack , Rth pack - ambient.

Comment: Thanks @SteveSh for the help ( I couldnt mention more than one user per comment.)

Comment: @KIRAN S - You can mention as many users as you want in your comment.  Just leave off the "@" sign.  Most users, when they start commenting on a question, also follow the question.  So they get notified of any comments or answers (I think), and so will see your "thanks".